# How to calculate Total for particular column value?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have table like below:

```
col1     col2
 1         20 

 2         40

 3         60
```

I want to output table like the following one :

```
col1     col2
 1         20 

 2         40

 3         60

total    120
```

I am using the following code but it doesn't work.

```
 object total = dtprofit.Compute("Sum(col2)", string.Empty);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you use in C# ? WinForms ? DataGrid ? I have so many questions to you but you have to provide some explanation. Do not let us to guess.

Comment: am using winforms datatable using c#

Comment: What't the type of `col2`?

Comment: Let's assume that is `int`

Comment: If it would be of int, and there are no nulls, then the code you have provided works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var total = table.AsEnumerable()
                 .Sum(dr => dr["col2"] is int ? (int)dr["col2"] : 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
    Int32 sum = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in YourDataTable.Rows)
                sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(dr["col2"].ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString()); //
```

Comment: @andy Never seen RAMARAJ.M mentioning optimalization.

Comment: @andy I accept that it is an old method but it is still a right answer. it is also very helpful for beginners. By putting -1 you are demoralizing everybody.